# Reading a file in C as utf-8 and iterating through each character?

Tags: c, unicode

How would I go about reading a file in C, then iterating through each character so I can evaluate it? So for instance, I would give the input file of: `5 ≠ 10`, evaluate that as 5 is not equal to 10, and print out false. Now I can do the evaluation part, but I'm unsure how to approach reading unicode characters in C. I'm asking this question, since I've written a larger lexer, and I want to have it support unicode, however I wanted to try it out on a smaller-scale project to see how it goes.

Comment: What platform are you working with?

Comment: The `≠` character is three bytes: E2 89 A0. The `10` is two bytes: 31 30. What is the difference with parsing them?

Comment: @Michas There's 3 bytes in one, and 2 in the other? I dunno

Comment: @iharob I'm not too sure what you mean, if you mean OS I'm on Linux. However, this is for a compiler, so it should be cross-platform.

Comment: Why don't You parse `≠` the same way You parse `10`?

Comment: @Michas easier said than done

Comment: @metro-man use a library that knows how to handle UTF-8. There's no other practical option.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: A Flex-generated parser can recognize `!=` (a two-byte sequence) as a not-equal token; it could recognize the three byte `≠` in just the same way. The problem isn't recognizing operators. It's recognizing identifiers. However, that's still possible; it just requires a really big regex (still just a few kilobytes of transition tables, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is an encoding format for Unicode. What you're actually interested in is parsing the text and separating out each byte. Then you need to calculate the Unicode code point to determine the character.

Ultimately you need:

> 1. A parser that can distinguish utf-8 character boundaries.
> 2. A translator to convert the data encoded as UTF-8 into a Unicode code point.
> 3. And a reference list of code points and their semantic meanings.

The Not Equal To sign is Unicode code point U+2260. Which is encoded in UTF-8 as 0xE2 0x89 0xA0.

EDIT: You should be using a library for parsing UTF-8 text. What you should be focusing on is finding the code points that are relevant to your application, and interpreting their meaning within your application.

Comment: Is writing a parser, and a translator, etc. a pretty big task?

Comment: I haven't done it. But you have to find the character boundaries of multi-byte characters, then pull out individual bits(and groups of bits) from multiple bytes and convert that into a Unicode code point. You should start by reading how UTF-8 encodes code points.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I'll check out some specifications, and a few articles about unicode... hopefully I can get myself into the right direction from there. If all else fails, I'll just use an existing library. Your answer seems to give me enough to start off with, so I'll accept it, cheers :)

Comment: None of these three steps is a big effort; #3 might end up being a lot of typing, depending on what characters you care about.

Comment: #1 and #2 are trivial. #3 is the killer, since you have to sift through 1 million code points to find the ones you care about.